# How do I store particular JSON data as a list in python

Tags: python, json

The API: https://api.covid19india.org/misc.json
I want all the population values in a list.
I tried this,

```
data = r.read().decode() 
js = json.loads(data)
xd = js['district_meta_data'][0]['district']
```

But this return only one value

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over json objects and append population in a list.

```
data = r.read().decode() 
js = json.loads(data)
l = []
for i in js['district_meta_data']:
    l.append(i['population'])
print(l)
```

or simply

```
l = [i['population'] for i in js['district_meta_data']]
```

Comment: `['district_meta_data'][0]` this gives you just first. `['district_meta_data']` try this.